# Getting the first collection item without breaking pager

Tags: magento

I posted a question about this earlier, but I have more information now and I thought it best to post a new one rather than modify (sorry if that's not proper protocol).  You can find my original question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6311646/magento-collection-catch-22/).

Anyhow, the initial problem was that I wanted to inspect the first item in a collection inside the List.php class just after setting the collection so that I could scrape the category and use that to show reviews.  This was all based off a custom module, so there were a lot of variables.  I have since tried it on a default Magento sample store and only added **ONE** line to `app/code/core/Mage/catalog/Block/Product/List.php` to break the pager.  Here are the details.  If you have any ideas why this is happening, please let me know as I'm stuck

First, open `app/code/core/Mage/catalog/Block/Product/List.php` and locate the `_getProductCollection` function.  At the end of the `if (is_null...)` block, add `$_foo123 = $this->_productCollection->getFirstItem();` so you have a function that looks like this:

```
protected function _getProductCollection()
{
    if (is_null($this->_productCollection)) {
        $layer = $this->getLayer();
        /* @var $layer Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer */
        if ($this->getShowRootCategory()) {
            $this->setCategoryId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId());
        }

        // if this is a product view page
        if (Mage::registry('product')) {
            // get collection of categories this product is associated with
            $categories = Mage::registry('product')->getCategoryCollection()
            ->setPage(1, 1)
            ->load();
            // if the product is associated with any category
            if ($categories->count()) {
                // show products from this category
                $this->setCategoryId(current($categories->getIterator()));
            }
        }

        $origCategory = null;
        if ($this->getCategoryId()) {
            $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($this->getCategoryId());
            if ($category->getId()) {
                $origCategory = $layer->getCurrentCategory();
                $layer->setCurrentCategory($category);
            }
        }
        $this->_productCollection = $layer->getProductCollection();

        $this->prepareSortableFieldsByCategory($layer->getCurrentCategory());

        if ($origCategory) {
            $layer->setCurrentCategory($origCategory);
        }

        //THIS LINE BREAKS THE PAGER
        $_foo123 = $this->_productCollection->getFirstItem();
    }

    return $this->_productCollection;
}
```

Now, simply go to any product list that uses that class (category view, for instance) and you'll see what I mean.  No matter what you choose under **Show XX per page** in the toolbar, it will always show you all items in the list.  If you comment out that `$_foo123...` line, it works fine.

What gives??

*P.S.  I know I'm not supposed to edit core files...this is just an example :)*

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The reason is because when you call `getFirstItem()` (or just about any other retrieval method) on a collection that collection is *loaded*. Any subsequent operation ignores the database and uses only the loaded data, filters have no effect because they are SQL only, ditto for pagination and selected columns. The workaround is to use a second collection based on the first.

```
$secondCollection = clone $firstCollection;
$secondCollection->clear();
$_foo123 = $secondCollection->getFirstItem();
```

The [`clear()`](http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Varien/Varien_Data/Varien_Data_Collection.html#clear) method *unloads* the data for that collection, forcing it to access the database again next time.

Comment: Thank you!  I knew that asking for an item in the collection effectively loaded it, but I didn't realize that would affect paging.  I thought the entire collection WAS the collection and the pager showed you parts of it, but I guess not.  Man, this stuff can be CONFUSING!

One question...did you mean to put the `clear()` line _before_ the `getFirstItem()` call?  Seems counter intuitive...

Comment: I intentionally put `clear()` before the second collection is used in case the first collection was already loaded. The `clone` clones everything.

Comment: Isn't it better to clone collection fully loaded - when it has all items? Then you don't have to clear it - you just clone full collection and on clone you call `getFirstItem()`

Comment: What if `getFirstItem()` isn't the only thing you want to do with that collection? There might be more filters to add, or some paging. That would change the meaning of which item is 'first'. Also by not clearing you are using the same instances of models, so if one is altered then the other collection's data is also changed in what is called a 'side effect'. It's better to code defensively and avoid any such problems.